# Styling Dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to css html and js.
My problem is that the dropdown menu is like half way out of the window and I don't know how I can position the dropdown menu. All the methods I tried didn't work. The second problem on my dropdown is that only if I click a certain part of the button, the dropdown menu actually appears. Can you guys help me out?
This is my code:

```js
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropdiv')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropdiv {
  background-color: #001155;
  width: 40px;
  height: 22px;
}
.dropdivs {
  height: 4px;
  width: 29px;
  background-color: white;
  color: white;
  border: #001155;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 2px;
}
/* Dropdown Button */

.dropbutton {
  background-color: #001155;
  color: white;
  padding: 13px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
/* Dropdown Links*/

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbutton">
    <div class="dropdiv">
      <div class="dropdivs"></div>
      <div class="dropdivs"></div>
      <div class="dropdivs"></div>
    </div>
  </button>
  <div id="inhalt" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="https://www.google.ch/">Google</a>
    <a href="https://intranet.swisscom.com/home/#/">Intranet</a>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/">Facebook</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is there a `onclick="myFunction()"`? It looks like a copy paste error,  is `myFunction()` actually defined somewhere?

Comment: its better if you use <select> tag and <option> tag for dropdown menu

Comment: Why don't u just add **right:0;** in your **.dropdown-content** CSS ? That seems to work for me.

Comment: @Vixed thanks that worked

Comment: @DBS yeah i think you are right

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer, but for me is not a good way to create a Dropdown menu, I'm sure that you will find new method on [Google](https://www.google.it/search?q=javascript+dropdown+mobile+menu), and for some tips: [Responsive Top Navigation](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav.asp) from *w3schools.com*

```js
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropdiv')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show'))
          openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      else
        openDropdown.classList.add('show');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropdiv {
  background-color: #001155;
  width: 40px;
  height: 22px;
}
.dropdivs {
  height: 4px;
  width: 29px;
  background-color: white;
  color: white;
  border: #001155;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 2px;
}
/* Dropdown Button */

.dropbutton {
  background-color: #001155;
  color: white;
  padding: 13px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  right:0;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
/* Dropdown Links*/

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}
.dropdown-content.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbutton">
    <div class="dropdiv">
      <div class="dropdivs"></div>
      <div class="dropdivs"></div>
      <div class="dropdivs"></div>
    </div>
  </button>
  <div id="inhalt" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="https://www.google.ch/">Google</a>
    <a href="https://intranet.swisscom.com/home/#/">Intranet</a>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/">Facebook</a>
  </div>
</div>
```